# Doxygen, Macro as type function / generic

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, documentation, doxygen

Because C does not have templates or generics in the same way other languages have, I  rely on Macros to achieve a similar effect. For example:

```c
#define OPTIONAL( T ) struct{ bool present; T data; }

OPTIONAL( size_t ) Example1( size_t x )
{
    return x ? { true, x - 1 } : { false, 0 }
}
```

However when documenting this with Doxygen it seems to sometimes trip on these sort of constructs, especially with typedefs

For Example:

```c
/** @brief example */
typedef OPTIONAL( size_t ) optional_size_t;
```

Produces the following warning

`warning: return type of member OPTIONAL is not documented`

It seems Doxygen sees this as a function definition with name `OPTIONAL` , return type `typedef` and input argument type `size_t`. And I guess `optional_size_t` is just forgotten.

Is there any way to remedy this. I'd rather not rely on `MACRO_EXPANSION` as some of these macros produce messy types (hence why I want to hide them behind macros) and the documentation of these macros are often better than there expansion.

So In a perfect world Doxygen would see `OPTIONAL( size_t )` identical to `std::optional<std::size_t>` and it would generate a link to `OPTIONAL` and to `size_t`.

**EDIT**

doxygen version 1.9.5

("relevant", not things like `PROJECT_NAME`) config options that differ from `doxygen -g default.cfg`

```
    OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
    QUIET                  = YES
    WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
    RECURSIVE              = YES
```

All other options that differ are local paths or things like not generating latex output.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at the setting `SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS`? Please show the settings in your settings file different from the default settings (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`).

Comment: Best idea: do not attempt template meta programming in C. If that's not an option for reasons unknown, then maybe consider naming the struct type after the member type instead. Call some macro as `declare_struct(size_t);` then declare the function as optional_size_t foo (void);`

Comment: How would that help in the following senario

`typedef OPTIONAL( size_t ) optional_size_t;` --

`void example( optional_size_t input );`

Wouldn't moving the typedef inside another macro break the link between `optional_size_t` and the actual `OPTIONAL` macro
@Lundin

Comment: What I mean is drop your current macro and replace it with something somewhat more sensible. For example something like `#define declare_struct(T) typedef struct { bool present; T data; } optional_##T`

Comment: But again, please note that the actual problem here is that you are trying to invent your own private macro language. And the solution to your root problem is to find out what  this type-generic programming is supposed to solve.

Comment: Doxygen issue: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9656